# Unity: Uploading image works on android but corrupted on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloudinary

I have a `byte[]` which represent an image. When I'm creating a texture from it and display it, the image looks ok so I know I've loaded it correctly.

Now I'm trying to upload it to a server (cloudinary) using this code:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddBinaryData("file", imageBytes);
form.AddField("api_key", "XXX");
form.AddField ("timestamp", timeNow);
form.AddField ("signature", "YYY"));
WWW www = new WWW("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ZZZ/image/upload", form);
```

this works perfectly when I'm running on android.

On iOS I'm getting a weird image that looks good only at the top of it (each time the image looks different):

Original Image:
[image: original]

Uploaded Images (all of them received on the server when loading the same image from the client):
[image: result1]
[image: result2]
[image: result3]

Any help will be really appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Can you get any upload response message, as that might give you further clues? [Cloudinary in this doc](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002587911-How-to-detect-corrupted-images) mentions it's possible to get an IsCorrupt status information. On another note, how big (in MB) is your byte upload? Cloudinary mentions uploading in chunks when it exceeds certain sizes.

Comment: Did you try [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) instead of the **obsolete** [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)? And could you add the part of code where you get the `byte[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got corrupted  files too. Both for image files and for audio files that consistently got noise in the first quarter of a second in the uploaded file.

I'm not sure if it was a Unity or an Apple bug, but updates seem to have fixed it:

Updated Unity to 2019.3.0f6

Updated Xcode to Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

The latest info I could find from Unity is to use:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddBinaryData("FileData", bytes, "tmp.byt", "image/jpg");

UnityWebRequest upload = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
upload.SendWebRequest();
```

Hope it works for others as well.